# Constructor not waiting for HTTP request

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have this constructor that checks the mobile app version:

```
  public Login() {
      InitializeComponent();
      loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
      this.BindingContext = loginViewModel;
      var upToDate = loginViewModel.CheckAppVersion();

      // It doesn't reach this section
      if (!upToDate) {
          Application.Current.MainPage = new UpdatePage();
      }
  }
```

It doesn't reach the section specified above so it doesn't redirect when the versions are not matched. This is my function for checking the app version vs the  updated version:

```
    public bool CheckAppVersion() {
        var httpClient = Globals.g_HttpClient;
        var request = new RestRequest("get_mobile_app_version");
        request.Method = Method.POST;
        request.AddHeader("KEY", Globals.APIKey);
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        var response = httpClient.Post(request);
        var contentResponse = response.Content;
        if (contentResponse == Globals.AppVersion) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I think it might be because the constructor isn't waiting for the API call's response before it finished loading the login screen, but I've tried putting `InitializeComponent();` in the bottom part of the construction but it's still the same.

Comment: I'd advise against putting HTTP API calls into your constructor.

Comment: What is type of `g_HttpClient` and what is ` httpClient.Post(...)`? Please review [MCVE] guide on posting code and [edit] question accordingly. (99% this is regular deadlock on someone trying to call async method synchronously)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov this is ```g_HttpClient``` - ```public static RestClient g_HttpClient = new RestClient("https://website.com/");```

Comment: @John so what should I do to check the current version vs the api version from the API upon the user launching the app?

Comment: constructor should not be async i.e. it should not be awaiting for anything, it should return constructed object type.
So I guess you'd need to create separate `async` method, inside it call post and use `await` to wait for result, then after getting result update whatever you need.

Comment: @paulitto but I cannot await inside the constructor. How do I call the async method when the user launches the mobile app?

Comment: @ehmhrgelcighsawmlv just call async method from constructor but don't await on it. Await inside this separate async method and handle awaited result there.

Comment: @paulitto this works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
public async Task<bool> CheckAppVersion() {
    var httpClient = Globals.g_HttpClient;
    var request = new RestRequest("get_mobile_app_version");
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    request.AddHeader("KEY", Globals.APIKey);
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, 
certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
    var response = await httpClient.Post(request);
    var contentResponse = response.Content;
    if (contentResponse == Globals.AppVersion) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And In your Constructor:

```
 public Login() {
  InitializeComponent();
  loginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
  this.BindingContext = loginViewModel;
  var upToDate = loginViewModel.CheckAppVersion().Result;

  // It doesn't reach this section
  if (!upToDate) {
      Application.Current.MainPage = new UpdatePage();
  }
```

}

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the result inside `CheckAppVersion` method:

```
public async void CheckAppVersion()
{
    var httpClient = Globals.g_HttpClient;
    var request = new RestRequest("get_mobile_app_version");
    request.Method = Method.POST;
    request.AddHeader("KEY", Globals.APIKey);
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

    //await here
    var response = await httpClient.Post(request);

    var contentResponse = response.Content;
    if (contentResponse == Globals.AppVersion)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = new UpdatePage();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could to change "async void" to "async Task<bool>" to check (and await) if the method return ok.